# Google Custom Search GCSE "Input Box Value"?

Tags: jquery, search, dom, google-search, google-custom-search

How to get the `value` of GCSE Inputbox? Its id is:

```
<input id="gsc-i-id2" ....
```

But i can NOT get the value of it by using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert( $( 'input#gsc-i-id2' ).val() );
})
```

It is NOT working. Why please?

**NOTE ** But in the Page Source, the whole Google CSE section is NOT visible :S

How to catch that box please?**

Comment: may be `<input id="gsc-i-id2"` is created dynamically with some google script.

Comment: yes correct. but how can i get its value, pls?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only item on that page with that ID?

Comment: Yes. Actually i have one at the top and one at the bottom. But the id's are unique, as you can see the suffix number. But in the Page Source, the whole Google CSE section is NOT visible :S